# Not able to get the current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I have been searching for this one for long time, found many links but none of them worked.

When i was working in webforms i was able to get the current user by the following code.

```
System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
 string user = identity.Name;
```

But in mvc project `current` does not work, so i tried it by

```
HttpContext.User.Identity
```

when i write identity.name it keep coming null again and again.

I am trying to get the UserName of current logged in windows user. how can i get that.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from within a controller action method? did you try **User.Identity.Name;**

Comment: yes i am accessing it within a action method, but it keep coming blank.

Answer (score -1):

From the *controller* you can directly try -

```
string user = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Have u specified <authentication mode="Windows" /> in config file?

Comment: You haven't given any replies to a person who tried to help you on that day, and gave a downvote for his effort after 3 weeks? Cool!!